# iOS Swift: UIPickerView Text Alignment

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uipickerview

Attempting to right/left align the text in two components in a `UIPickerView`. It's being displayed correctly inside of the selected zone, but the text is overlapping elsewhere.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    var titleData: String!

  if component == 0 {
      if pickerView.tag == 0 {
          titleData = weightData[row].description
      } else {
          titleData = bodyFatData[row].description
      }
      pickerLabel.textAlignment = .Right

  } else {
      titleData = decimalData[row].description
      pickerLabel.textAlignment = .Left
  }

  let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(22.0),NSForegroundColorAttributeName:

  UIColor.blackColor()])
      pickerLabel.attributedText = myTitle

      return pickerLabel
  }
```

[image]

EDIT:

When I add this line

`pickerLabel.frame.size = CGSizeMake(165, 26)`

It does have an effect, but the selected/unselected rows are still misaligned.

[image]

Comment: Would it help to give your UILabel a size?

Comment: Also, do not combine label text alignment with an attributed text. If you are going to use an attributed text, include the alignment in the attributed text paragraph style.

Comment: Try to add size to `pickerLabel` and also implement `rowHeightForComponent` function.

Comment: Changing the pickerLabel size does have an effect, but it doesn't appear to be possible to align both the selected and unselected text.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are simply overlooking the possibilities of this function:

```
// Swift
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(50.0)
}
```

[image: centered and tight components]

By default the components will center align, and it appears the whole picker will also center align. If you omit the `textAlignment`, all the values in a component (column) will line up.

Comment: This is actually a good thing to know thank you, It makes it look neater when only small amount of text